# Selenium ChromeDriver displays SessionNotCreated after launching Chrome and then exiting

Tags: powershell, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to create a PowerShell script to automate some testing tasks but falling at the first hurdle.

I have a folder with [ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=105.0.5195.52/) (chromedriver.exe) and the [Selenium Web Driver 4.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver) for .NET (WebDriver.dll).

On the test server, .NET version 4.8.03761 and Google Chrome 105.0.5195.102 (64-Bit) are installed.

After executing the script, Chrome is briefly launched and then exits. I see the following message in the PowerShell window:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102) (SessionNotCreated)"
```

In Task Manager, the ChromeDriver.exe continues to run. Subsequent runs yield the same
behaviour and message.

The script is:

```
$workingPath = 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\LaunchTest'
if (($env:Path -split ';') -notcontains $workingPath) {
    $env:Path += ";$workingPath"
}
$env:Path -split ';'
Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll"
$ChromeOptions = [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions]::new()
$ChromeOptions.AddArguments('start-maximized')
$ChromeDriver = New-Object -TypeName "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver" -ArgumentList @($ChromeOptions)
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('<https://google.co.uk>')
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced quite similar problem.
My solution:

- uninstall chrome 64-bit and remove its reminder
- install chrome 32-bit instead